# No way to have an IRI 1.4.2.2 fullnode synchronized

Tags: iri-node, syncing, nelson

For a long time I had a well synchronized 1.4.2.1 IRI fullnode running properly with neighbors managed by CarrIOTA Nelson.

Then I updated IRI to 1.4.2.2 version and I never succeded in having a fullnode running synchronized.

Every time the fullnode starts, with CarrIOTA Nelson dinamically providing the neighbors, `latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex` reaches a value which is a little less than `latestMilestoneIndex` and then it stucks on that value forever even if new transactions continue to arrive from the neighbors.

Of course I also tried to rebuild the `db` from scratch without success.

Is there anybody who is experiencing this behaviour with 1.4.2.2 version of IRI fullnode?

Comment: This could be one possible reason for the lowering of TPS value, at least as I happened to read lately on Discord channels.

Comment: same issue here. i have also tried to remove complete db.

Comment: @Saint Hill. You could be fairly right. Anyway I usually rely on Nelson for  managing neighbors and this always worked well for me until version 1.4.2.2.

Answer (score 1):

Probably due to this [this](https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/issues/585) open issue that says:

*latestSolidSubtangleMiletoneIndex does not update in 'getNodeInfo' until a system restart it updates. It just stays the same until a restart.*

So the fullnode is synchronized but following calls to `getNodeInfo` doesn't return updated values for `latestSolidSubtangleMiletoneIndex`.

Answer (score 0):

I have mi IRI 1.4.2.2 up & synced since the release day. I did not have good experiences with Nelson. Instead I used [this guide](https://forum.helloiota.com/2424/Setting-up-a-VPS-IOTA-Full-Node-from-scratch) (writen be me). it might not be the most complete guide but my node is always synced and allows me to use my wallet in a neat way.

I only have 4 neighbors and they are 100% stable. I think that, as CFB stated some time ago, less ir more when it comes to this matter. 4 stable fully synced neighbors gave me an awesome performance so far.

Comment: One the missing parts in the guide (that I will add sooin) is the one related to boot the 30 minutes old mainnetdb in order to speed up a lot the sync process. This image can be found here http://db.iota.partners/IOTA.partners-mainnetdb.tar.gz and should replace whatever you have in your mainnetdb.

Comment: [This continues the comment above]. @CarpinchoDem As I wrote in my question I always had a 1.4.2.1 IRI fullnode plus Nelson synchronized. When I upgraded to 1.4.2.2 I never succeded in having a syncronized fullnode running. Nelson manages neighbors also limiting their numbers.